# Inverses of homotopic paths are homotopic too

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> PROVE: If $g_1 \simeq g_2$, then $\bar{g_1} \simeq \bar{g_2}$.

I found the solution online [*here*](https://onesidey.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/hatcher-1-1/), which I copy it down here for convenience:

(1) Let $\bar{g_1} : I \to X$ be defined by $\bar{g_1}(s) = g_1(1-s)$, and similarly $\bar{g_2}(s) = g_2(1-s)$ 
(2) Let $H(s, t)$ be a homotopy from $g_1$ to $g_2$ so that $H(s, 0) = g_0(s)$ and $H(s, 1) = g_1(s)$ 
(3) Define $\bar{H}(s, t) = H(1 - s, t)$ 
(4) The map $(s, t) \to (1 - s, t)$ is a homeomorphism from $I \times I$ to itself, so we see that $\bar{H}(s, t)$ is a homotopy from $\bar{g_1}(s)$ to $\bar{g_2}(s). \quad \blacksquare$

Do you have alternative proof that is more intuitive than the above? I especially found (4) un-intuitive, can you explain it in differently? Thanks for your time and effort.

---

PS: This question looks very classic, but I am surprised that it was never asked before. The only closest sibling similar to mine is *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524492/proof-that-two-homotopy-inverses-are-homotopic)*, but they are not the same. The same question was raised *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524492/proof-that-two-homotopy-inverses-are-homotopic)* but the proof was not given. Let me know if you found any.

Comment: What part of the proof don't you understand? Do you agree that $f\colon I^2\to I^2\colon (s,t)\mapsto (1-s,t)$ is a homeomorphism? Do you agree that the composition of continuous maps is continuous? Do you then agree that if $H\colon I^2\to X$ is continuous, then $H\circ f$ is continuous? Hence $\bar{H}$ (which is equal to $H\circ f$) is continuous.

Comment: @DanielRust : Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key in (4) is that $(s, t) \mapsto (1 - s, t)$ is continuous which follows from the fact that $s \mapsto 1 - s$ is continuous.

Notice what the domain and codomain of $H$ are, that is, $H : I \times I \to X$. We defined $\overline H : I \times I \to X$ by $\overline H(s, t) = H(1 - s, t)$. We can define $\varphi : I \times I \to I \times I$ by $\varphi(s, t) = (1 - s, t)$ which we've just established is a continuous map. Notice that $$\overline H(s, t) = H(1 - s, t) = H\big( \varphi(s, t) \big).$$

or in the form of a commutative diagram:

$\hspace{7cm}$[image: Commutative Diagram]

Then $\overline H$ is a composition of $H$ with a continuous function. Since $H$ is a homotopy by hypothesis, it is continuous, so the composition is continuous.

Now just notice that $$\overline H(s, 0) = H(1 - s, 0) = g_1(1 - s) = \overline g_1(s)$$ and similarly $$\overline H(s, 1) = H(1 - s, 1) = g_2(1 - s) = \overline g_2(s)$$ which tells you $\overline H$ is a homotopy between $\overline g_1$ and $\overline g_2$.

The person who wrote the original proof added more information than needed: they said $(s, t) \mapsto (1 - s, t)$ was a homeomorphism (which is true), when all we needed was continuity.

Comment: (1) Your first paragraph makes a world of sense than the original proof! (2) On your second paragraph, I saw that Daniel Rust mentioned also $\bar{H} = H \circ g$, which is similar to what you said in the beginning of this paragraph. Could you please elaborate a little bit? (Nice to meet you again! You seem to forget you are talking to a slowpoke.)

Comment: I saw your edit and I am still digesting it, but in the meantime while you are still here: Let say that I have finally convinced myself that indeed $\bar{H}$ is continuous, but how do you link $\bar{H}$'s continuity to the fact that $\bar{g_1} \simeq \bar{g_2}$? I mean the gap between the two. Thanks again as always!

Comment: @A.Magnus updated answer.

Comment: Yes sir, I saw your nice diagram and the update, I am still reading it even as we speak. Thanks again and again.

Comment: On your nice little diagram, I saw that kind of diagram a lot in abstract algebra. Does it shortcut to say that if the two "legs," which are $\varphi$ and $H$, are continuous, then the "hypotenuse" will also be continuous? Or is it just a fool's conclusion? Thanks.

Comment: It's true! The composition of to continuous functions is continuous! Make sure you can prove that to yourself!

Comment: Could you do me a small favor? Can you take a look at my earlier posting [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182567/is-the-interval-0-1-in-homotopy-subset-of-real-number) and help me with (2) and (3) only, I think I am pretty OK with (1) and (4). Even after long comments and counter-comments, I am still as confused as a lost dog in a busy street. That is, if you have extra time. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm reading it over. It may take some time to digest. I'll try and give you some feedback!

Comment: Cool! But never mind if you running out of time. Thanks again.

Comment: I hope you can get this message. I have second thought about asking you to look at my earlier posting [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182567/is-the-interval-0-1-in-homotopy-subset-of-real-number). Never mind about my request, I have been asking too many from you already. I am sorry for demanding too much. Thanks again for all you have been doing to help me.

Comment: Don't worry! I'll take a look at it in a bit. It looks interesting, it's just very detailed and I need to sit down to read it carefully!

Comment: @A.Magnus, added an answer to your post!